# Laravel 5.8 passport logout method ( Unauthenticated )

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, bearer-token

when i call route `/api/logout` i getting `Unauthenticated`, i already have tokens from my `/api/login` methods, also when i try run demo request with same `middleware` it works perfect

- i tried request like demo:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

**route ( in api.php with api prefix )**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/logout', 'PassportAuthController@logout')->name('api.auth.logout');
```

**simple logout function**

```
public function logout( )
    {
        auth()->user()->tokens->each(function ($token, $key) {
            $token->delete();
        });

        return response()->json('Logged out', 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auth()` is a helper function where you cant pass parameter of the auth you use

specially if you use multiple auth systems so you should determine which auth ?

so to be sure that you logout from api auth not the default auth write

```
public function logout( )
    {
        auth('api')->user()->tokens->each(function ($token, $key) {
            $token->delete();
        });

        return response()->json('Logged out', 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Auth is correct as you are using Auth API in route middleware.

Instead of `auth()->user()->tokens`

use `auth('api')->user()->tokens`